# Saving a variable as a file name and importing a function from the saved variable name - Python

Tags: python, function, file, variables, import

Okay, so this one really bugs me. I want to ask the user what file I should open in Python and from that answer, I should be able to import the file. For example:

```
e = input('File Name?')
from e import *
```

However, this results in a syntax error, where it says that there is no module 'e'. How do I fix this?

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't really make sense. Once you've imported the file, what do you think you can do with it?

Comment: I smell the [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Please describe the use case in which user input should determine what package (you import a package, not a file) you import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `importlib`.

```
import importlib
file = input('Enter: ')
mymodule = importlib.import_module(file)
```

You can access variables and functions like `mymodule.func1()`.
More information [here](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/import-python-module-string-name)

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to open the file to read the contents you're looking for the `open` command.

Example:

```
e = input("Enter file: ")
file = open(e)
contents = file.read()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It answers a different question you're guessing about.